# JQuery: on('Click') not responding to newly-prepended button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, django

I have a working Django application in which I use JQuery to send AJAX to server side when new comment is submitted by user. Specifically, when a user submits a new comment, it triggers the following JQuery function:

```
$(":input[type='submit']").on('click',function(event){
     // send AJAX to Django views.py
     }
```

When the JSON data is back from `views.py`, it will prepend a HTML block containing the new comment text to the current page without refreshing the page. The problem is that this new HTML block also contains `input[type='submit']` elements. But when I click these elements, they are not responding and the json.dumps in `views.py` unable to detect them. Obviously when clicking the button, the above JQuery function does not trigger.

I checked the "view source" in Chrome. These HTML do appear in the source. It is just not responding and the the HTTPResponse will just return a JSON dict plain text, which is a sign that the the jQuery function does not trigger.

Appreciate if anyone could give me a hand.. Thank you!

Comment: Can't answer without seeing HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.on events are only picked up for elements that exist at the time of the declaration.

From the jQuery docs - http://api.jquery.com/on/

> **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().**
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

So to use delegated events you want to attach the on event to the parent element e.g. if you are attaching the new comments to an element #container

```
$("#container").on('click','input[type=submit]',function(event){
   // send AJAX to Django views.py
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/eg0yx920/